# git repository ignoring all .dlls

Tags: git, gitignore

Title says it all. I am trying to add my NuGet packages to the repository. Everything but the .dll files are being detected.

The gitignore file contains no references to *.dll. The .dll files don't get recognized when located anywhere in the entire repository. info/exclude is also empty.

I have also cloned the repository (file-system to file-system as opposed from remote to file-sysytem) with no luck. This issue also happens on two different computers.

I could add the .dll files manually, but they should be tracked. Why are they not being tracked?

Comment: What does `git config --get core.excludesfile` say?

Comment: Also it is generally not a good idea to use git for tracking binary files as git cannot efficiently calculate deltas between revisions so keeping all versions will be a waste if space. If dlls are generated on-the-fly it is better to just ignore them in git. If they are not - it is better to use another sync mechanism (eg rsync).

Comment: These are NuGet packages I am trying to add to git. I am not using the  "Package Restore" functionality of NuGet so I need the entire packages folder checked in.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Do you have either `~/.gitignore_global` or `~/.gitignore` in your home directory which could also be listing these file patterns?

See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

Comment: Given that he's working with dll files, he's on Windows platform, so ~ means $HOMEDRIVE $HOMEPATH under Windows 7

Comment: This turned out to be the issue. I did not add this global ignore file though. Any reason why it would just pop out of nowhere? Now that I think of it, I recently installed SourceTree (from Atlassian). Maybe it is the culprit?

Comment: I had the same issue, I also installed SourceTree prior to that. So I guess it's a fair guess that SourceTree added the global ignore file since it used to work in the past.

Comment: Edit: OK, it's added by SourceTree [link](https://twitter.com/daniellangnet/status/314634981110591488)

Comment: First time I pushed after updating a load of packages since downloading source tree. This took far to long to identify as a problem. Anyone raised this as an issue with the sourcetree team?

Comment: I had to run `git check-ignore` to find out where the file was. Fond it at ~/Documents/gitignore_global.txt

Comment: Source Tree has a nice UI but (very discreetly) introducing an additional, external, global gitignore into the system git is a TERRIBLE idea and I wasted several hours pulling my hair out over this crap. I feel like dumping Source Tree just for this.

Comment: This was the issue for me also. I suspect it was Visual Studio that caused the filter in my case given the comment `#Ignore files build by Visual Studio` that was in there.

Comment: @DavidWatts Is this gitignore_global.txt mentioned in your ~/.gitconfig file?

Comment: @MattCanty Is gitignore_global.txt mentioned in your ~/.gitconfig file?

Comment: @Apelsin Is there any mention of gitignore_global.txt in your ~/.gitconfig? That how I found it pretty quickly myself. I'm wondering if I was just in luck.

Comment: "~ means $HOMEDRIVE $HOMEPATH"
not exactly, its %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%

Comment: It is happening to me on a work computer and I don't even have sourcetree installed.    Just Git bash and then GitHub Desktop.   -  Not seeing a global gitignore anywhere

Answer (score 104):

If you use SourceTree and the default setting it will ignore all DLLs by default... Tools=>Options=>Git then "Edit File"... add a "#" before *.dll => "#*.dll" ... save and close.

Then for Windows Explorer in your packages folder in open a GitBash terminal and type "git add ." and let it work, back into SourceTree wait a second and all those missing package DLLs will show up for you to commit and push.

Comment: Correct answer for SourceTree users ;)

Comment: Did know about a global ignore list, couldn't find it in the GUI.. Thanks!

Comment: Tools => Options => Git/Mercurial Global Ignore List ... If you dont have one you can create and point to it there.

Comment: File location: ~/Documents/gitignore_global.txt

Comment: This worked for source tree, but how for visual studio the ignores weren't in my gitignore. Any I used source tree for this task

Comment: What a really stupid thing to do... it's really silly assuming that a repo won't be using dynamic libraries etc. that are needed for the program to compile and function. I'm glad I found this answer!

Comment: The file SourceTree uses is `$HOMEDRIVE\Documents\gitignore_global.txt`

Answer (score 11):

> I could add the .dll files manually, but they should be tracked. Why are they not being tracked?

No, they *shouldn't* be tracked, unless you've added them. Only files which are already added and committed are tracked; that's what "tracked" means.

Try manually adding one of them via `git add` and it will *tell* you why it's ignoring them, and prompt you to use `git add -f` to add the file anyways.

Comment: I did a "git add '/packages'" and it didn't detect the .dlls. I then used -f and it added it. I found the issue though. "*.dll" was in my global ignore. No clue where this global ignore came from.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly tell git to track any new files.

1. Run `git add filename` to add the file to git's index.
2. Run `git commit` to commit changes in your index.

`git status` should also show the list of untracked files and directories.

If you want to list all the files in the repo which are ignored by gitignore, you can run:

```
git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others
```

If you want to list all the untracked files in the repo:

```
git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others
```

Comment: I had to "git add -f" to track the files that were in fact ignored. It turned out to be an entry in the global ignore file, which some application has put there for my unknowingly.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue. I am unable to add .dll file from package directory to my git then i found gitignore_global.txt file as sourcetree automatically added this file as a global git ignore setting. I removed *.dll from gitignore_global.txt file and its work fine for me.

Location of gitignore_global.txt file as below

C:\Users\XXXX\Documents\gitignore_global.txt or you can find it out from sourcetree TOOL => OPTION => GIT tab and find out global ignore list

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there were no .dll references in the .gitignore file, and I had no global file.  However, in the .git subdirectory, I found a file called ms-persist.xml.  I closed all instances of Visual Studio, and then added my missing .dlls manually to that file.  When I re-opened visual studio, the .dlls were showing as needing to be checked in.  I checked them in and now I'm golden...

Answer (score 1):

You have a global `.gitignore` somewhere or further `.gitignore` files in subdirectories - relative to your project's root.

On Linux Systems and MacOS the global git-ignore is most likely in your Home `~/`

`~/.gitignore_global`

On Windows it is likely in your User Directory. Either your local user (which you can find out by typing in `ECHO %USERPROFILE%` or `whoami` at the command-line.

If it is not there, then surely a `.gitconfig` is present instead. Look herein for the location of the gitignore (e.g. the User's `Documents` folder).

**Edit**: 
Use `git config --list --show-origin` to get details of the contributing git-settings and their corresponding file locations.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I'm adding for others who may visit this question in the future. You can go modify your global ignore file as the answers above mentioned, but that will affect ALL of your git repos. If, instead, you'd like a more granular approach, you can just exclude either specific DLLs or specific folders in your individual project .gitignores. This overrides the all ignore settings and forces the files to be detected and handled by git. I think this is a better approach.

.gitignore (for your particular project)

```
# Custom ignores
!*.dll
# or
!My.specific.dll

# rest of .gitignore
```