# how to add dlls to bitbucket using sourcetree

Tags: git, dll, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to upload a .net project to bitbucket repository. For this I'm using atlassian SourceTree. First when I upload the working directory, it didnot show the dlls in working copy changes or staging changes.

However after changing the global ignore list (tools->options->Git->EditFile), removing the dll entry, it started showing. But the staged changes are not pushing to the repository. It always says up-to-date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git repository ignoring all .dlls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515729/git-repository-ignoring-all-dlls)

Answer (score 12):

I just took a stab at this.

I first had to see the dll files in the SourceTree GUI, so I selected the 'Ignored' option from the dropdown on the Commit form.

[image: SourceTree Commit Dropdown]

Then I checked each one.  As I did, the file was added to the Pending list.

[image: Ignored checkboxes]

Answer (score 1):

Staged changes aren't enough: they need to be committed fist, before being able to be pushed.

Note that dll are ignored by default, because they are supposed to be:

- generated from the source
- downloaded from a declaration (like a [Nuget file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9466844/6309))

, and are not versioned in a *source* version control system.