# Microsoft.Owin dll missing after push to git

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, git, github, owin

I have duplicated the problem I am having by creating a brand new MVC 5 project, by default some authentication code is added in when you start a new MVC 5 project.  I created a couple of controllers, a couple of views, some shared views for a Layout, and it all runs as expected.

Then I create a new repository on bitbucket, tried github as well.  I copy and paste all the contents of the solution into this newly created repository folder, then commit and push to my new git repository.  This all still works fine locally.

Then I try to pull this repository into a new folder to simulate someone else pulling from my repository.  When I do all the Microsoft.Owin dll's have the little yellow triangle , showing that they can't be found.  When I try to build there are like 26 error's or something like that , because Owin and Owin.Security aren't there .  If I go into Manage NuGet references and re-install Microsoft.Owin , then I have to go and re-install several other dll's then I get it to work.

I have no idea what is creating this,  has anybody have any idea why this is happening , or what I can do to make the build just work the first time after a pull?

Comment: Unfortunately git doesn't seem to work well with Visual studio projects and related files. I have used git extensively on Linux based projects and it works without any issues. My solution was to switch to svn. I would say I eventually did get it to work ok but for several dependency, environment and file naming properties reasons git is not quite there yet on windows. Just my findings.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515729/git-repository-ignoring-all-dlls

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sourcetree as your git client it blocks dlls by default

Open Tools>Options

Open Git tab

Global Ignore File: Select 'Edit File'

Comment out the line that says *.dll